# How to put the Mac Mini to sleep (without logging in) when the screen is locked?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, screen-lock

The screen is locked after some time. That is ok. Then some minutes or hours later I come back. Sometimes I want to get in again, then I need to log in. But sometimes I just want to send the machine to sleep or to halt it right away. I want to do these without first logging in.

Comment: Aren't there buttons for this at the bottom of the login screen? See for instance image at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63289/grey-login-screen-after-enabling-encryption

Comment: @lhf Even without screen controls (which some organizations or settings suppress ), the keyboard shortcuts cover this functionality - it's just a matter of memorizing them or understanding how to map a non-mac keyboard to the media eject key ion software if you don't have an Apple Keyboard on the mini.

Comment: I do not see any buttons at the bottom. Is it because I'm using Big Sur 11.3 beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disconnect the display in this case for sleep if I can't remember the shortcuts that I don't use often.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

> - Option–Command–Power button* or **Option–Command–Media Eject** : Put your Mac to sleep.
> - Control–Shift–Power button* or **Control–Shift–Media Eject** : Put your displays to sleep.

For shut down, you can also log in - either via screen sharing, ssh, Apple a Remote Desktop or remote scripts if you need to sleep or power off the display and haven't memorized the commands above.